# If my employment pass got rejected what should I mention in column "have you ever been refused a visa for any country" in my new UK visa application

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, visa-refusals

If my employment pass got rejected what should I mention in column "have you ever been refused a visa for any country" in my new UK visa application

Comment: Do you mean a Singapore [Employment Pass](http://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits/employment-pass)? I'd guess yes this does count as a visa - [this page says their passes are commonly known as 'work visas'](http://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits) - but I can't say authoritatively. I expect your safest option is to say yes and explain the reasons you weren't issued an employment pass - from the UK's point of view I expect they're most interested in the grounds for your refusal.

Comment: Yes it is Singapore employment pass.....I am confused because it was not applied by me....my to be employer has applied and got it rejected ....there are many reasons ...including the employer's profile as well....also if you have employment pass....still you need to visa to enter singapore right?

Comment: The answer is one word: 'yes'.  Done and dusted

Comment: @GayotFow : So you are saying ...In my current visa application to UK ...I should answer yes for the column "have you ever been refused a visa for any country"

Answer (score 1):

Long story short - never lie on an application, the ramifications are far worse for you and you'll never get a chance to appeal if caught out (well, you might but they'll already be looking for a reason to deny you).

IF you feel it might be not-quite-sorta accurate, or you want to provide an explanation, write that you have, then put a * next to it, and attach a letter at the end explaining it truthfully and what happened.  Your goal is to answer any lingering doubts they may have about you, so try to cover everything.